# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;(Hibernate)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to add order in database. My order consist of: user_id, flight_id, name, surname, phone, mail.

**Order:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order extends BaseEntity {
    private User user;
    private Flight flight;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String phone;
    private String mail;

    public Order() {
        super();
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "flight_id", nullable = false)
    public Flight getFlight() {
        return flight;
    }

    public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
        this.flight = flight;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "surname", nullable = false)
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Column(name = "phone", nullable = false)
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Column(name = "mail", nullable = false)
    public String getMail() {
        return mail;
    }

    public void setMail(String mail) {
        this.mail = mail;
    }
}
```

**Method to add new order:**

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void createOrder(Long idFlight, Long idUser, String name, String surname, String phone, String mail) throws ServiceException {
        Flight flight = flightService.getById(idFlight);
        User user = userService.getById(idUser);
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setFlight(flight);
        order.setUser(user);
        order.setName(name);
        order.setSurname(surname);
        order.setMail(mail);
        order.setPhone(phone);
        try {
            orderDao.add(order);
        }  catch (DaoException e) {
            logger.debug(e);
            throw new ServiceException(e.getMessage());
        }
        mailService.sendNotification(name, surname, mail, flight.getNavigation());
    }
```

**Logs:**

```
8463 [DEBUG] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.462 jdbc.spi.SqlStatementLogger.logStatement(SqlStatementLogger.java:92) - insert into order (flight_id, mail, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into order (flight_id, mail, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 8464 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.463 jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.register(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:55) - Registering statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@1c0d1aa4: insert into order (flight_id, mail, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **, ** NOT SPECIFIED **)]
 8465 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.464 persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2709) - Dehydrating entity: [by.netcracker.artemyev.entity.impl.Order#<null>]
 8466 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.464 descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
 8467 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.465 descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) - binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [bart@gmail.com]
 8468 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.465 descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) - binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [Bart]
 8469 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.466 descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) - binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [777777777]
 8470 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.466 descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) - binding parameter [5] as [VARCHAR] - [Simpson]
 8471 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.467 descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:65) - binding parameter [6] as [BIGINT] - [3]
 8472 [DEBUG] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.468 jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:124) - could not execute statement [n/a]
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (flight_id, mail, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (1, 'bart@gmail.co' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2542) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1734) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2019) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1937) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1922) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:98) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:205) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2909) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3480) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:623) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:277) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:258) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:303) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:773) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) [spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.persist(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.dao.GenericDao.add(GenericDao.java:40) [classes/:?]
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.createOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:45) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.createOrder(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.web.order.OrderController.updateFlight(OrderController.java:37) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
 8473 [WARN ] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.510 jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:129) - SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
 8474 [ERROR] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.511 jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(SqlExceptionHelper.java:131) - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (flight_id, mail, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (1, 'bart@gmail.co' at line 1
 8475 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.532 jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.release(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:68) - Releasing statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@1c0d1aa4: insert into order (flight_id, mail, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (1, 'bart@gmail.com', 'Bart', '777777777', 'Simpson', 3)]
 8476 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.533 jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.close(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:148) - Closing prepared statement [com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement@1c0d1aa4: insert into order (flight_id, mail, name, phone, surname, user_id) values (1, 'bart@gmail.com', 'Bart', '777777777', 'Simpson', 3)]
 8477 [TRACE] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.533 jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.afterStatementExecution(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:263) - Starting afterQuery statement execution processing [ON_CLOSE]
 8478 [DEBUG] 2017-05-30 00:59:59.534 jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:255) - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:255) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:143) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.Transaction.markRollbackOnly(Transaction.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.markForRollbackOnly(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.handlePersistenceException(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:271) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:148) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:155) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:162) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:780) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758) [hibernate-core-5.2.9.Final.jar:5.2.9.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298) [spring-orm-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40.persist(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.dao.GenericDao.add(GenericDao.java:40) [classes/:?]
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.service.impl.OrderServiceImpl.createOrder(OrderServiceImpl.java:45) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy53.createOrder(Unknown Source) [?:?]
    at by.netcracker.artemyev.web.order.OrderController.updateFlight(OrderController.java:37) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) [catalina.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1354) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.0.M18]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
```

I can't understand why I have this problem. This script in MySql

```
INSERT INTO `airline`.`order` (`name`, `surname`, `phone`, `mail`, `user_id`, `flight_id`) VALUES ('Matt', 'Dushen', '798-76-13', 'matt@gmail.com', '3', '1');
```

doesnt have error.

*How fix this?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Order` is an SQL keyword. Rename your table to something else

```
@Table(name = "my_order")
```